# Routing ionic 3 on app open best practices & patterns ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing

Hello ionic community.

I’m currently porting a large codebase from ionic 1 to ionic 3

On app open, I have to route to different pages based on conditions from firebase.

What are the best practices and patterns here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your code on app.component.ts. An example:

```
const authObserver = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if (user) {
        this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
        authObserver.unsubscribe();
    } else {
        this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
        authObserver.unsubscribe();
    }
});
```